# Selecting data from more than 2000 databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How i can search / select a field in more than 2000 databases in sql server.
i have a main database consisting a table called 'Kewword" where i store key world under 'kewwordtitle' field in keyword table, when new user register a new database are created for the user and user use a keyword,
now the situtation is, how i can find that how much user use a key work, here keywordtitle is primary key,...
thanks/

Comment: Can you tell us more about your database design? Why does every user have its own database?

Comment: @MichelZ maybe they're doing this to bypass the max database size limit in SQL Express.. or they provide users with direct access to the database and there's no technical way to prevent users from accessing the each other's data without this separation

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit fuzzy, but if this is a one shot and if all your databases are on the same instance, you could do something like:

```
declare @t table(col int)

insert @t 
    exec sp_MSforeachdb 'use ?; select 1 from keyword where keywordtitle = ''<yourkeyword>'''

select count(*) from @t
```